# Port Python Code to Android

Tags: android, python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am having some Python code that heavily relies on numpy/scipy and scikit-learn. What would be the best way to get it running on an Android device? I have read about a few ways to get Python code running on Android, mostly Pygame and Kivy but I am not sure how this would interact with numpy and scikit-learn.

Or would it be better to consider letting the android application send data to some server where Python is running?

Comment: That's a hard situation… You'd better use Java™ from the start, as it's the most portable way. Write once, run everywhere — that's Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the sound of it I'd suggest making a simple Django server, free hosting available at pythonanywhere.com

If you don't know Django just go through the basic tutorial. Follow it step by step and you'll be a set within just a few hours. Follow the tutorial and implement the example simultaneously using pythonanywhere.

Once you're comfortable just make a URL that your Android app can send a GET request to and receive in either JSON or REST format the information that you need.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/

http://pythonanywhere.com/

Running code like numpy and scipy on your phone won't be very fast either if there is considerable amounts of computations behind it. Far better to run the computations on the server and just retrieve it on the Android app.

You can send the parameters as part of the GET request. Configure the urls.py of the Django app to receive those parameters and pass it to views.py where you execute your scripts to work on them and then send back the response.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you need....

Python on a server using Flask/ Django would allow you to build an http UI or even an API interface for your Android (or any) device.

Qpython is a brilliant way to run python on an Android but probably won't cope with the whole of scipy so depends on what libraries have already been ported across by the Qpython team. It's a great tool though and worth a look anyway.

IMHO learning a bit of flask for server side running would be easier and more flexible than using Kivy.